# Replacing numbers with letters in string

Tags: r, gsub, ff

I have an ID column with names like "155AB3EA157A3466887D8F4B99BABC35". I want to replace the numbers in these strings with letters. I've tried using `gsub`, but it produces an "invalid text argument" error. My code looks like this:

```
as.character(df$ID)
gsub("1", "A", df$ID)
```

I should add that I'm working with the `ff` package, because the data is very large.

Comment: what would be your expected output for above string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF we are replacing numbers 1-9 with LETTERS 'A' to 'I', then `chartr` is an option

```
chartr('123456789', 'ABCDEFGHI', v1)
#[1] "AEEABCEAAEGACDFFHHGDHFDBIIBABCCE"
```

#### Update

Just noticed that the OP was probably using an `ffdf` object

```
library(ff)
library(ffbase)
```

In that case, applying the functions in the regular manner results in error as the OP mentioned

```
gsub("1", "A", d$v1)
```

> Error in gsub("1", "A", d$v1) : invalid 'text' argument

So, we can use the specialized extraction functions like `with.ffdf` or `within.ffdf` from `ffbase`

```
with.ffdf(d, gsub("1", "A", v1))
#ff (open) integer length=1 (1) levels: A55AB3EAA57A3466887D8F4B99BABC35
#                         [1] 
#A55AB3EAA57A3466887D8F4B99BABC35
```

For replacing the numbers 1-9, the `chartr` can be applied as

```
d$v1 <- with.ffdf(d, chartr('123456789', 'ABCDEFGHI', v1))
d
#ffdf (all open) dim=c(1,1), dimorder=c(1,2) row.names=NULL
#ffdf virtual mapping
#   PhysicalName VirtualVmode PhysicalVmode  AsIs #VirtualIsMatrix PhysicalIsMatrix PhysicalElementNo #PhysicalFirstCol PhysicalLastCol PhysicalIsOpen
#v1           v1      integer       integer FALSE           FALSE            FALSE                 1                1               #1           TRUE
#ffdf data
#                                v1
#1 AEEABCEAAEGACDFFHHGDHFDBIIBABCCE
```

#### data

```
v1 <- "155AB3EA157A3466887D8F4B99BABC35"
d <- as.ffdf(data.frame(v1))
```